# Deleting Perforce Workspace from cloned VM

Tags: perforce, workspace, p4v

Does deleting a workspace only affect local files in perforce, or is there some bookkeeping kept by the perforce server? I've cloned a VM and now have two of the same workspaces on two separate machines, but want to remove one from one machine but not the other. How can this be done?

Comment: To clarify: on your new second VM, do you wish to have a copy of your workspace files, or not? If you simply don't want the files, just rm -rf that workspace folder, as the original workspace is still resident on the original VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting a workspace deletes it from the server, so you definitely don't want to do that.

In your new VM, create a new workspace. If you want it to be exactly the same as the original VM, create the new workspace by using the original workspace as a template. From P4V, right-click on the workspace from the Workspace view and choose "Create/Update workspace from originalworkspace"

Or, from the command line:

```
p4 client -o -t originalworkspace mynewworkspace
```

Comment: I'd also suggest editing the Host field on your original workspace so you don't accidentally use it with the new VM.